# When layout each case except the only main content

Tags: php, opencart

I have using With the following code In **Latest Module**. but It is not working in latest module.

Following code add in **latest.php**

```
$this->data['column_left'] = array();
$this->data['column_right'] = array();
```

Following code add in **latest.tpl**

```
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
            <?php $class_grid = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
            <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
            <?php $class_grid = 'col-sm-4'; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <?php $class_grid = 'col-sm-3'; ?>
            <?php } ?>


    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
     <div class="<?php echo $class_grid; ?>">
       <div class="product-item>....</div>
     </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I get this results:

[image: screenshot]

I want to this:

[image: screenshot]

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: I saw similar question here some time ago... Was it you who was asking? Your English is terrible, I cannot even guess what are you trying to say in the first and second chapter...

Comment: Yes, it is similar. but, It was working perfect in category page(category.tpl). but, it is not working in Latest Module(latest.tpl). Thanks.

Comment: where do the `$column_left`and `$column_right` get their value?

Comment: @RST I have update our code. I hope, You have understand now.

Comment: So you have described the expected behavior, but what is the error/problem here? I don't get it from the question.

Comment: @shadyyx I have update Our question with screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $class_grid = 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12';
    if ($column_left && $column_right) $class_grid = 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12';
    if (($column_left && !$column_right) || (!$column_left && $column_right)) $class_grid = 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12';
?>
```

Comment: this is not work. I have update Our question with screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: this should work unless the value of your `$column_left` and `$column_right` variables is not present. Add this above the code  `echo "left $column_left<BR />";echo "right $column_right<BR />";` to check the values.